# Flutter image not loading error " Invalid image data"

Tags: flutter, image, dart, file-upload, flutter-image

I am trying to load an image from the assets which is not working I am able to load network image and also some other images also in the png and jpg format but I don't know why the required images that I am trying to load are not working. Some one help me in that what might be the specific problem. I am sharing the pubspec.yaml and also the assets folders images which are correct to the point. [image]

I tried the network image also which is working and also tried some other images but I don't know why the required images are not working.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you added such lines to pubspec.yaml file?

```
  assets:
     - assets/images/onboarding_images
```

Comment: Yes I've tried this also but this also didn't work

Comment: the same image is also working in jpg format but i want the transparent background so png is must in that case and png is not working

Comment: In that way, take any PNG file (i.e. download it from flutter.dev)
If the file works then the problem is in your PNG files.

Comment: as I mentioned earlier the other png files are also working so may be the problem is in the png file. the svg is not working jpg working but not needed png not working I don't know what to do. by the way thanks again for guidance.

Comment: SVG might not be working properly. I've experienced many such cases. I refer to these SVG files as broken. They might be displayed in a browser but be useless in a Flutter app.

Comment: That's insightful about svg files I'll keep this in mind for future.

Comment: Could you provide this png image?

And about SVG: it will work fine only if it's a real SVG - without png importing in svg's data. You can check it by opening svg in notepad (or some other text editor)